# Where is trizen after it is built?

Tags: arch-linux, application

I read the following instructions for installing Google Earth on Arch:

```
 cd ~/installs
 git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/trizen.git
 cd trizen
 makepkg sri
 trizen -S google-earth-pro
```

The last step failed because there is no trizen binary. `which trizen` fails to find any version of trizen on the computer.

Comment: Just install trizen with pacman? `pacman -S trizen` then run `trizen -S google-earth-pro`

Comment: btw `makepkg` will create a package something like `trizen.tar.xz` which you'd need to install with `pacman -U trizen.tar.xz` btw#2 `which` searches only for binaries in directories which are in your env var `PATH`. In this case you need to do a `find . -iname "*.tar.xz"` in the git cloned directory.

Comment: Shouldn't `makepkg sri`  be `makepkg -sri`?.  Is that a mistake in what you did or in the transcription?

Comment: @MichaelD. the `-i` in `makepkg -sri` stands for "install".  It will install the package using pacman after building without the need for `pacman`

Comment: @MichaelD. trizen is in [the AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/trizen/).  It's been a few years, but I don't remember pacman pulling from the AUR.  `yaourt` can do it, (and apparently `trizen` too) but not `pacman`.

Comment: @Stewart `trizen` is available with pacman on manjaro. It's probably different from arch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was a copy and paste typo:

```
makepkg sri
```

should have been:

```
makepkg -sri
```

The typo caused the package to get built, but never installed. Since the build completed successfully, I didn't realize that no install had occurred. One way to check if something is installed is to run the installation again:

```
makepkg --clean
makepkg --install
```